# How do I use LanguageTool API from Rapid API to check a string in Java?

Tags: java, string, languagetool

This is the code Rapid API created for me.

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(URI.create("https://dnaber-languagetool.p.rapidapi.com/v2/check"))
        .header("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .header("x-rapidapi-host", "dnaber-languagetool.p.rapidapi.com")
        .header("x-rapidapi-key", "[redacted to prevent abuse]")
        .method("POST", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString("text=This%20is%20a%20error.&language=en-US"))
        .build();
HttpResponse<String> response = HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
System.out.println(response.body());
```

This is what it outputs:

```
{"software":{"name":"LanguageTool","version":"5.5-SNAPSHOT","buildDate":"2021-09-17 18:41:41 +0000","apiVersion":1,"premium":false,"premiumHint":"You might be missing errors only the Premium version can find. Contact us at support<at>languagetoolplus.com.","status":""},"warnings":{"incompleteResults":false},"language":{"name":"English (US)","code":"en-US","detectedLanguage":{"name":"English (US)","code":"en-US","confidence":0.528}},"matches":[{"message":"Use “an” instead of ‘a’ if the following word starts with a vowel sound, e.g. ‘an article’, ‘an hour’.","shortMessage":"Wrong article","replacements":[{"value":"an"}],"offset":8,"length":1,"context":{"text":"This is a error.","offset":8,"length":1},"sentence":"This is a error.","type":{"typeName":"Other"},"rule":{"id":"EN_A_VS_AN","description":"Use of 'a' vs. 'an'","issueType":"misspelling","category":{"id":"MISC","name":"Miscellaneous"}},"ignoreForIncompleteSentence":false,"contextForSureMatch":1}]}
```

It seems to be working, but how do I make it so it checks my strings instead of the one they gave me?

Like if I had `String myString = "Hello World. Hello World. Hello World."` and I wanted to check this, where would I put the string in the code they provided to me?

I tried doing `.method(myString)` but it's not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to look at the API docs, but it seems you need to update the request body

I'm not familiar with this http client class, but either in the method

```
String x = "This is a error.";
... 
.method("POST", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString("text=" + URLEncoder.encode(x, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()) +"&language=en-US")
.build();
```

Or the `HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString()` needs to be given some similar input